# Can anyone please show a simple example of using BeautyTips?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, beautytips

Looking for a simple example of how beautytips can be used( HTML + CSS included)?
My requirement is this - I am displaying product names.On hovering of product name,I want to display products image in the tooltip.How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: @spinon I *love* the "Tip of the day" section: `Choose an eyeliner that suits your eye color.` and, `Wear a Hairstyle that complements your dressing and personality.`

Comment: @Pekka Yeah that is pretty sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website with some samples:
http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html

Assuming that is that you are referring to this jquery plugin.

Comment: That demo page is NOT useful - it uses a complex eval method to run javascript in a textarea - what the gentleman is asking for (and what would be useful to all of us) is a BASIC example of a page with a div that initiates a simple bubble when you hover over it. WITHOUT any flair... please.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. You just have to make sure the js files are getting loaded. Note that i'm using hoverintent lib here to give a delay before anything pops up.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.bt.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.hoverIntent.minified.r6.js">
<div id="mydiv">Mouse over here to see it poppin'</div>
<script>
$("mydiv").bt("Text to pop out",{
            showTip: function(box){
                $(box).fadeIn(300);
            },
            hideTip: function(box, callback){
                $(box).animate({opacity: 0}, 100, callback);
            },
            hoverIntentOpts: {
                interval: 1000,
                timeout: 200
            },
            fill: '#E1EEF8',
            cornerRadius: 10,
            strokeWidth: 0,
            shadow: true,
            shadowOffsetX: 3,
            shadowOffsetY: 3,
            shadowBlur: 8,
            shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,.9)',
            shadowOverlap: false,
            noShadowOpts: {strokeStyle: '#999', strokeWidth: 2},
            positions: ['top', 'bottom','right']
        });
</script>
```